# Can Quarriors' Ghostly Spirit be destroyed more than once?

Tags: quarriors

The Ghostly Spirit's special ability is:

> When Ghostly Spirit is destroyed, you may cull 1 Basic Quiddity Die to return Ghostly Spirit to your Ready Area (for free).

For example, let's say that I've got a level 1 Ghostly Spirit and an Assistant in my ready area, and my opponent attacks me with strength 4. I defend first with my Ghostly Spirit and it's destroyed, but then what? Can I cull a quiddity die to return it to my ready area and then use it to defend again? Or do I have to finish defending, let my Assistant be destroyed, and then cull a quiddity die to return my Ghostly Spirit to my ready area?

If you can cull the die before finishing the defense, we've had situations where a player culled several dice in one turn.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Quiltimate Quedition rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/183173) at the top of page 7:

> If an effect or ability prevents a Creature’s destruction or returns a destroyed Creature to your Ready Area (such as a Life Charm), you may not assign any more damage to that Creature this turn.

So you can't use the same die more than once in a single defence.